# How to create varien object in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, object

In magento 1 we can create varien object like this

```
$collection = new Varien_Data_Collection(); 
$varienObject = new Varien_Object();
$varienObject->setData($data);
$varienObject->setItem($item);
$collection->addItem($varienObject);
```

How to create object in magento 2?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Magento 2 the `Varien_Object` equivalent is `\Magento\Framework\DataObject.` The class name was changed from Object to DataObject because object is a [reserved word](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.other-reserved-words.php) in `PHP 7`. So you could use something like:

```
$obj = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
$obj->setItem($item);
```

**Update 2018**

This answer intended to illustrate an answer the original question in the most succinct way possible and not in the context of a real code example.  Although it did answer the question, `\Magento\Framework\DataObject` is the new `Varien_Object`, the implementation wasn't 100% in line with Magento 2 best practice. As @MatthiasKleine pointed out, Magento 2 best practice to create objects in your code is to use Magentos DI framework to inject a [factory](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/factories.html) into your class via the constructor and use that factory to create your object. With that in mind, using DI to create a DataObject in your own code should look something like this:

```
namespace My/Module;

class Example {
    private $objectFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $objectFactory
    ) {
        $this->objectFactory = $objectFactory;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function doSomething($item)
    {
        $obj = $this->objectFactory->create();
        $obj->setData('item', $item);
        //or
        $obj->setItem($item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This throws a warning when running 'phpcs --standard=MEQP2':
Direct object instantiation (object of \Magento\Framework\DataObject) is discouraged in Magento 2.

Comment: @JeroenVermeulen-MageHost right, but it's just a *warning*, to make you aware of a *potential* error. For the `DataObject`, I'd argue that there is no benefit in dependency injection and factories. It's just a glorified array after all.

Comment: How to assign multiple array value in the object? **@Andrew**

Comment: It will be better to use  `$obj->setData($item)` instead of `$obj->setItem($item)` This way you will be able to get any field value of `$obj` using method directly. Like `$obj->getName()` etc.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of creating the object with 'new' you should use DI (Dependency Injection) to inject the Factory class and use that factory to create new instances of DataObjects.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory
 */
private $dataObjectFactory;

public function __construct(
    // ...
    \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $dataObjectFactory
) {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->dataObjectFactory = $dataObjectFactory;
}

public function yourCode()
{
    $dataObject = $this->dataObjectFactory->create();
}
```

Comment: This way is correct way for declaring data object, when you follow coding standard like MEQP/MEQP2/PSR etc...
Thanks...

Comment: Thank a lot -): It works like charm for me.

Comment: How to assign multiple array value in the object? **@Matthias**